# Nominative Case Assignment and VP-Internal Subjects

Tags: syntax, greek, cases

From what I've learnt, structural case is assigned in certain structural configurations. For example, nominative case is assigned by tensed I/T to nominals in SpecIP/TP. Therefore, the case filter allows the nominal subject to become overt.

My question relates to the VP-internal subject hypothesis. In Greek, the subject is said to be able to remain in SpecVP:

```
Diavaze  sihna   o   Janis     to  vivlio 
Read-3SG usually the Janis-NOM the book-ACC
```

If NOM is always assigned in SpecIP, how is "o Janis" able to obtain NOM?

Comment: Sometimes SpecIP is locked up because the watchman is taking a break, so they hafta assign NOM in SpecVP, even though the plumbing there needs repairs.

Comment: The languages of the Balkan sprachbund are nonconfigurational. That is, there's no VP. Case isn't assigned structurally in such languages. Whatever is the subject gets the nominative case (in Greek) assigned by an exocentric rule.

Comment: @Atamiri, according to Tesniere's verb centrality, there is no finite VP at all. So the terms "configurational" and "nonconfigurational" are valid only for those theories of syntax that acknowledge this unit, i.e. the finite VP constituent. In other words, all languages are nonconfigurational according to Tesniere, not just the Balkan languages. And what is an "exocentric rule"?

Comment: @TimOsborne A configurational language is one in which grammatical relations are signaled (predominantly) structurally (in actual fact, configurationality is a scale). There are no phrase structure rules in DG so "configurationality" has to be expressed otherwise but it is trivial to see that regardless of what theory one takes some languages signal GRs more by morphology whereas others by structure (word order). The question presupposes a theory based on phrase structures. (An exocentric rule is one that isn't endocentric.)

Comment: @Atamari, OK, thanks for the clarification. What you write is mostly verified by linguistics dictionaries. But a definining trait of configurational languages is the putative existence of a finite VP constituent. Falk (2001: 21) writes the following in this regard: "Languages like English, in which a VP constituent distinguishes SUBJ from OBJ, can be called configurational languages". Thus what I wrote is apparently also mostly accurate, since the presence/absence of the finite VP constituent is decisive for distinguishing between configurationality and non-configurationality.

Comment: @Atamiri Can you please tell me what this exocentric rule is? Since there is no VP in non-configurational languages and generative grammar uses the VP, is it more appropriate to explain this by adopting a different theoretical approach, say using DG?

Comment: @Adam An exocentric rule is one that doesn't have a categorical head. In your example it's something like S -> V NP NP. It's been first used by Ken Hale to describe the syntax of Warlpiri (he coined the term "nonconfigurational"). Some derivatives of GG don't use VPs (for some languages). As for DG, it's an alternative approach to syntax and it's often used to describe free word order languages. I wouldn't say it's more appropriate (nor less), it's just different.

Comment: One further comment concerning VPs and DG is worthy here, I think. This comment is that dependency-based syntax really cannot acknowledge the existence of a finite VP constituent. However, DG can easily acknowledge the existence of nonfinite VP constituents. This issue is important, since those who do not know DG jump to the inaccurate conclusion that it rejects all VPs.

Comment: @TimOsborne Yes, this is one definition of what nonconf. means so in this sense what you wrote was accurate. I personally think that this definition of configurationality (as a binary parameter) is too simplistic. It it a scale since nonconfig. languages have VPs too in some constructions. BTW in DG parlance, a "conf." language is one that tends to use LP rules to capture GRs whereas a "nonconf." language would prefer ID rules for this. The latter case could be split into two subcases: head-marking vs. dep-marking. I once wrote a grammar for Abkhaz, a caseless ergative language, that does this

Comment: @TimOsborne This is interesting. How does it acknowledge nonfinite VPs? Some Slavic languages have only nonfinite VPs.

Comment: @Atamiri, we agree almost entirely -- who'd of thunk? One quibble, however: I think we are tending to overuse acronyms (BTW, DG, VP, LP, GG, GR, ID); when too many of them appear, it's a hindrance to good communication.

Comment: @Atamiri, have a look at the section with the trees here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase. A constituent in DG is a complete subtree. Constituency tests are almost unanimous in verifying that these constituents exist, i.e. nonfinite finite VPs exist as constituents, and DG readily acknowledges this fact. Concerning your statement of the nonexistence of finite VPs in some Slavic languages, DG rejects the existence of all finite VP constituents, regardless of the language. The emphasis here is on the distinction between finite and nonfinite VP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21542/discussion-between-atamiri-and-tim-osborne).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the OP seems to want is a solution consistent with **his own** (broadly late P&PT) assumptions, not lessons on alternative theories of syntax in which his problem may not arise (if it doesn't; we would have to look at that in some depth).

Although I know nothing about Modern Greek and I am not even familiar with the way(s) generative syntacticians have analysed Greek clause structure either, herebelow is a proposal that, in my view, solves the OP's problem.

Assuming that things in Greek are as the OP says (i.e., that *o Janis* sits in Spec VP, whereas the verb has ascended into Infl/Tense), and assuming the - now obsolete - theoretical framework he refers to (basically that of *Barriers* plus the VP-Internal Subject Hypothesis of late P&P Theory), in which Nominative Case is still 'assigned' by T, etc., there **are** ways to assign Nominative Case to a VP-internal subject *in situ*. The obvious one is *via* association of the VP-Internal subject with an empty category (possibly a 'dummy' or 'little pro', see below) in Spec T, under the assumption that, for Case (agreement, categorial, and thematic) purposes, both are links of **the same** (subject) 'chain'.

Note that in English existential sentences like *There has been **a student** waiting for you in your office the whole morning*, *a student*, which remains in Spec VP (compare with ***A student*** has been waiting for you in your office the whole morning, where it has ascended to Spec T), is said to receive nominative Case *via* association, within the same 'chain', with the 'dummy' *there* that occupies Spec T. Recall that, since Spec T is not an a-(rgument) nor a th-(ematic) position, when the subject does not ascend from Spec VP into it, it **must** be occupied by a 'dummy' *there*, and only 'dummy' *there* can locally 'receive' 'structural Case' from +Tense. That - plus satisfying the Projection Principle, and doing so by providing phonetic content, since English is not a 'pro-drop' language and needs something pronounceable in Spec T - is the only function of 'dummy' *there*. Then, so the standard explanation goes, the subject *in situ* satisfies the Case Filter because the 'dummy' *there* associated with it does receive structural Nominative Case, cannot 'absorb' it (because it is not an argument), and must leave it 'available' in the subject chain for the NP *a student* to 'absorb' it. All that is consistent with late P&PT.

Back to the Greek case the OP asks about, to solve his 'problem' it would suffice to claim that *o Jannis* is also part of a subject 'chain' that contains a higher link in Spec T. The difference would be that, Greek being a 'pro-drop' language, that 'link' would not need to have phonetic content.

Depending on which version of P&PT one subscribed to, that 'silent' higher chain-link might correspond to the 'little' *pro* assumed to 'fill' apparently empty subjects in other 'pro-drop' languages (Spanish, Italian) or be filled by a phonetically empty Greek correlate of English 'dummy' *there*.

In either case, such a pro/dummy-DP chain would not cause any unification trouble at all, because a) there is **no** conflicting PF content (which **is** a unification problem in the case of English *there*-DP chains!), b) there is a single (Agent) theta role (assigned to *o Janis* in Spec VP), c) there is a single Case (Nominative, structurally assigned in Spec T, but 'absorbed' by the overt DP *o Janis* in Spec VP), and d) there is a unique set of Agreement ('phi') features (here: person, gender, number) inherently provided by the overt DP *o Janis* in the lower chain link.

Thus, as far as I can see, such sentences are not problematic for late P&P Theory.